# Evernote sync boost

Tags: evernote

I develop an app with evernote integration and want to clarify some things about Initial sync boost. [The documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/rate_limits.php#forclientsthatsync) says that

> The increase will be effective for 24 hours after an authentication
>   token is issued

so this boost applies to user's token ? If so, when a user, for some reason, wants to reauthorize himself with another token, will this boost be reapplied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be reapplied.  In order to accomplish that, the user needs to go to **My Account Page > Applications** and click **Revoke Access** for your app; then use whatever authorization UI you've built to perform the authorization again.